# gvfs-mount not working on Ubuntu 14.04 for wireless HDD

Tags: wireless, mount, samba

In **12.04**, I would mount a wireless HDD (Windows share?) using the following command

```
gvfs-mount smb://10.0.0.17/public
```

Then `~/.gvfs` will contain the mount.
In 14.04, when I do this.   The command doesn't give any error message but

1) I get permission denied when I try to access `~/.gvfs` and

2) it is **empty**.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The location for gvfs mounts had changed in Ubuntu 14.04.

Example of an SSH mount:

```
/var/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=COMPUTER,user=USERNAME/...
```

- 1000 is the user id of the standard user USERNAME
- sftp is the protocol used